# Jquery UI Modal Dialog not working in IE6 & IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

Im having problems with this modal dialog. It looks ok in all the browsers except IE6 and IE7.

In those browsers the dialog appears by default with a display:block. (like the jquery wasnt' working).

I have read in onlder stackoverflow posts that maybe the problem was with the version of jqueryui, But I have all the latest versions of jquery and jquery ui. =(

Could you help me? Why is this happening?

I made a fiddle...only for you to see all the code (including the scripts I embebbed in the head tag): http://jsfiddle.net/sh9qM/33/

Thanks in advance!
Orangejuice.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the classic "IE doesn't like trailing commas" problem:

```
$( "#dialog-modal").dialog({
    // ...
    title: 'My Title',
    //---------------^
});
```

Remove that last comma and things should work better. IE interprets the trailing comma as an extra empty object in your options and that causes some trouble.

Comment: I cant believe it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IT WAS A COMMA!! OH-MY-GOSH!! many thanks!!!